# Autofac InstancePerLifetimeScope in Web API models

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm having trouble setting up dependency injection for models in Web API 2.2. Specifically, the way I'm currently doing this results in any "InstancePerLifetimeScope" dependencies behaving as "SingleInstance" dependencies.

Here's what I'm currently doing with my JSON.NET resolver:

```
public class AutofacContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacContractResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        if (_container.IsRegistered(objectType))
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => _container.Resolve(objectType);

        return contract;
    }
}
```

What's happening is `_container.Resolve(objectType)` resolves the same instance for each request. This reaks havoc because I now have services running on two different sessions, one of which is outdated.

I think the Resolve call is happening before the request scope is created. It would explain the above behaviour, but I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the contract resolver so it gets used?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ILifetimeScope instead of IContainer.

```
public class AutofacContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _container;

    public AutofacContractResolver(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        if (_container.IsRegistered(objectType))
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => _container.Resolve(objectType);

        return contract;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior is the same with ILifetimeScope. However I did notice the ILifetimeScope Tag was "root" - this is further evidence that the ContractResolver is running outside Autofac's request scope.